# Need a Trigger to Copy New row to other table With some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have 2 tables (A,B).

- table A has these fields ( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...30).
- table B has these fields ( 1,2,3,6,7).
- The main table is A - data is inserted into Table A by a sales system .

I need trigger to do this :

Copy a New row inserted to table A and field (3) > 1  and field (7)!=''
To table B.

Note : there are huge data inserts to table A (at peak times) for that need code not effect performance.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, I would phrase this as;

```
create trigger trig_tableA_insert on tableA after insert
as begin    
    insert into tableB (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field6, Field7)
        select i.Field1, i.Field2, i.Field3, i.Field6, i.Field7 
        from inserted i
        where i.field3 > 1 and i.field7 <> '';
end;
```

This is safe for statements that insert multiple rows at one time.

If you have lots of inserts, I wonder if this is the best approach.  Presumably, you need the data right away in `tableB`, because triggers incur overhead.

Answer (score 0):

here's your `trigger`. adding below `condition` will not insert data to your `tableB`.

```
create trigger [t_TableA]
on tableA
after  [insert]
as
begin

    if ((select 1 from inserted where field3 > 1 and coalesce(field7, '') != '') != 1)
        begin
            return;
        end

    insert into tableB (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field6, Field7)
    select Field1, Field2, Field3, Field6, Field7 from inserted
end
```